# Disable Column Cell Selection

Tags: ag-grid

I would like to make a column not be able to be selectable.  I currently have icons in the column and whenever the cell is clicked it gets the clicked effect. The icons trigger a modal window, so when the window is closed the  cell has the clicked effect.   Is there a column definition that disables the cell selection of all cells in the specified column?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your column definition to override the border style that's applied to the cell on focus

```
cellStyle: {border: 'none !important'}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This should disable the click effect as OP has asked.

Comment: thanks @Tim L setting the border to none removes the cell boarder, exactly what I needed. Looks like there is no options to suppress cell selection at the column level.